# Calculation of the difference between two dates based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, date-difference, julian-date

will be very grateful for any help you can provide related to the following situation.

I have 2 tables and 3rd table which is a joined table of those 2 tables.

Each table contains information on stage changes where for my calculation important are old value of stage field, new value, and date of change.

In case there is a only date1 in table 1 I use the following SQLite code

```
select *,         case when `Duration1` = 0 then 1 else Duration1 end as "Duration1"

from 
(select * ,

coalesce(JULIANDAY(`date2`) - JULIANDAY(`date1`), `report2: Stage Duration`)
as "Duration1"
from table)`
```

In ideal scenario table 1 contains project and 1st date (date1), table 2 contains project and 2nd date (date2). I can join them and I can get 3rd table with 1st and 2nd dates and calculate the difference between 2 dates there.

The complication pops up in cases when I have 2 dates in table 1 and 1 date in table 2. Here I need a help. I would like to add a condition in SQL code saying

```
if count(dates from report 1/date1)>count(dates from report 2/date2)
```

the difference should be (Duration I need) calculated as

```
today - max(JULIANDAY(`date1`))
```

This is my first question here. Thank you for you help and understanding in advance!

Comment: Your question needs to be formatted better ie: code needs to be isolated and what language you are using needs to be in question more clearly including tags. I suggest reading some example questions and do some research in the help section of this site. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I agree, Saro.  Please edit and re-submit your question showing us a few lines of data from each of the table that you are speaking of.  Also, be sure to focus your question on **what** you need to answer, not **how** you are now attempting to answer it.  *(Look up the term:  "XY Problem.")*  We all want to help you, but we *(well, I at least ...)* really can't understand what you are asking here . . . welcome, and please try again.

Comment: Thanks, will try!

Comment: Also, it helps that you show some work under a header so that contributors know you have put forth some effort to solve problem. Kind of like showing your work when solving a math problem in school. Just asking for an answer likely leads to unanswered questions. Good luck! Can you show columns of each table in question  too please?